# How to contact Google support regarding the free products?

Tags: google, google-calendar

I want to add the holiday calendar from Switzerland to my calendar but it is not available (yet). So I wanted to contact Google if they are planning to add it. When I look for help I always end up in Google Groups but I don't think that they are watching those groups for suggestions.

Is there a possibility to contact Google support in another manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google employees do watch the discussion groups. Also, feedback from other social channels may be monitored as well, depending the product.

Google doesn't discuss upcoming launches or releases in general. In most cases, the best response you'll get for this feedback is "Thanks". So, even if feedback is acknowledged, it isn't specific enough be immediately satisfying.

Calling, emailing or posting in a Google forum won't get you information about product releases that are otherwise unavailable through blogs or other public channels.

Comment: Thanks. Then I'll watch the groups if someone is responding.